# taking N values from each partition in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Assuming I am having the following data:

```
val DataSort = Seq(("a",5),("b",13),("b",2),("b",1),("c",4),("a",1),("b",15),("c",3),("c",1))
val DataSortRDD = sc.parallelize(DataSort,2)
```

And now there are two partitions with:

```
scala>DataSortRDD.glom().take(2).head
res53: Array[(String,Int)] = Array(("a",5),("b",13),("b",2),("b",1),("c",4))
scala>DataSortRDD.glom().take(2).tail
res54: Array[(String,Int)] = Array(Array(("a",1),("b",15),("c",3),("c",2),("c",1)))
```

It is assumed that in every partition the data is already sorted using  something like `sortWithinPartitions(col("src").desc,col("rank").desc)`(thats for a dataframe but is just to illustrate).

What I want is from each partition get for each letter the first two values(if there are more than 2 values). So in this example the result in each partition should be:

```
scala>HypotheticalRDD.glom().take(2).head
Array(("a",5),("b",13),("b",2),("c",4))
scala>HypotheticalRDD.glom().take(2).tail
Array(Array(("a",1),("b",15),("c",3),("c",2)))
```

I Know that I have to use the `mapPartition` function but its not clear in my mind how can I iterate through the values in each partition and get the first 2. Any tip?

**Edit**: More precisely. I know that in each partition the data is already sorted by 'letter' first and after by 'count'. So my main idea is that the input function in `mapPartition` should iterate through the partition and `yield` the first two values of each letter. And this could be done by checking every iterate the `.next()` value. This is how I could write it in python:

```
def limit_on_sorted(iterator):
    oldKey = None
    cnt = 0
    while True:
        elem = iterator.next()
        if not elem:
            return
        curKey = elem[0]
        if curKey == oldKey:
            cnt +=1
            if cnt >= 2:
                yield None
        else:
            oldKey = curKey
            cnt = 0
        yield elem

DataSortRDDpython.mapPartitions(limit_on_sorted,preservesPartitioning=True).filter(lambda x:x!=None)
```

Comment: does it matter how the end result is _partitioned_? In other words - if you get the same results but partitioned differently, would that still be OK? The filtering would still be based on the original partitioning as expected.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* you don't really care about the partitioning of the *result*, you can use **`mapPartitionsWithIndex`** to incorporate the partition ID into the key by which you **`groupBy`**, then you can easily take the first two items for each such key:

```
val result: RDD[(String, Int)] = DataSortRDD
  .mapPartitionsWithIndex {
     // add the partition ID into the "key" of every record:
     case (partitionId, itr) => itr.map { case (k, v) => ((k, partitionId), v) }
   }
  .groupByKey() // groups by letter and partition id
  // take only first two records, and drop partition id
  .flatMap { case ((k, _), itr) => itr.take(2).toArray.map((k, _)) }

println(result.collect().toList)
// prints:
// List((a,5), (b,15), (b,13), (b,2), (a,1), (c,4), (c,3))
```

Do note that the end result is not partitioned in the same way (`groupByKey` changes the partitioning), I'm *assuming* this isn't critical to what you're trying to do (which, frankly, escapes me).

**EDIT**: if you want to avoid shuffling and perform all operations within  each partition:

```
val result: RDD[(String, Int)] = DataSortRDD
  .mapPartitions(_.toList.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.take(2)).values.flatten.iterator, true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe I should mention it in the question. The reason why I want to use `mapPartition` is because I want to avoid the shuffling between partitions for efficiency reasons. In your solution with `groupByKey` there is shuffling.

Comment: I see. Edited my answer to include a solution with no shuffling (preserves partitions)

Comment: Your answer is correct. My concern is about the `groupBy(_._1)`. Why do I need to group when i know that the values are already sorted by letter and after by count? I have updated my question to make more clear my idea.